# How to embed a staircase within an oddball task

Tags: python, psychopy

At the moment I try to create a visual oddball task with a staircase procedure embedded in it (using Psychopy v1.81.03, builder version). The odds should follow the staircase (gabor patches that change orientation). Standards should be gabor patches oriented vertically.
I started with creating a simple random trial_loop. Within that loop I inserted code components looking like this:

For the "begin of the experiment" I defined an orientation variable (also referring to it in the interface, in which the properties of the gabor patch are defined) and the staircase:

```
 orient = 20
 staircase = data.StairHandler(startVal = 20.0,
                  stepType = 'lin', stepSizes=[8,4,4,2,2,1,1],
                  maxVal = 90, minVal = 0, nUp=1, nDown=3, nTrials = 50)
```

For the "begin of the routine" I defined the presentation of the stimuli
and an if-statement that should choose the orientation depending on if it is a standard or an odd.

```
# ratio of oddball and standard
oddORstand = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2][randint(0,10)]
 # choosing orientation and correct answer depending if it's standard or odd 
if oddORstand == 1: #standard
    orient = 0
    corrAns = None
else: #odd
    for thisIncrement in staircase:
        orient = orient + thisIncrement
        corrAns = 'space'
        break
```

For the part that "ends the routine" I defined the response that should change the future orientation of odds depending on if it was a correct answer (detection - spacebar pressed) or not:

```
if oddORstand == 2: #it was an odd
    if key_resp_stand.keys == 'space': #space bar pressed, correct answer
        thisResp = 1
        staircase.addResponse(thisResp)
    elif key_resp_stand.keys != 'space': #space bar was not pressed, wrong answer
        thisResp = 0
        staircase.addResponse(thisResp)
    else:
        pass
```

In general, this works somehow (standards and odds are presented randomly and also the odds change their orientation but not in a manner that would make sense or that was intended).
I could imagine that the response is not correctly detected or added to the staircase. Another possibility might be that the for-loop to set up the orientation of odds is somehow wrong.
But since I never get an error message and I'am also relatively new to psychopy it is a bit tricky for me to figure out the problem.

Is someone out there who can help me with this issue? That would be more than great.

Thank you so much in advance,

Hannes